# IIS error 403 not logged and showing unknown error page

Tags: iis, iis-8

When I try to access a page on my IIS web I get an error 403. The error is not logged to the log file and the error page shown is not the one that's defined in the config.

That's the content of the error page:

`<html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head><body>Access denied</body>`

Can anyone help me to find this error page and get the error logged?

Answer (score 0):

The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code that means that accessing the page or directory you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason.

To resolve this issue, you need to enable directory browsing for your application. To enable directory browsing on IIS, check out the steps from this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/directorybrowse).

If you still can’t solve the problem, you can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Comment: I know what a 403 error is. But why isn't it tracked in the logs? Enabling directory browsing doesn't change anything. You link for failed request tracking is for rewrite rules. I don't use rewrite rules here.

Comment: Failed request tracking is not only applicable to rewrite rules, it can also be used directly based on the status code. make sure enable the Failed Request Tracing in Web Site Failed Request Tracing Settings dialog box.